# Sketching dynamics of Bloch vector for ground state with dynamics induced by Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, bloch-sphere

How can I sketch a Bloch vector for a system that is in the ground state |g> that is induced by Hamiltonian $ H_x = \frac{ω_x}{2}σ_z$? Is there a general method that I can follow for drawing Bloch vectors depending on the system's state and the Hamiltonian inducing the Bloch's vectors dynamics?

Comment: Think about how the Bloch vector is defined...

Comment: are you asking how to draw the Bloch vector corresponding to given ket state?

Comment: @glS yes, but I'm also asking what the method is for drawing the Bloch vector for any given ket